# Отличия интерпретаций JS в Opera и Firefox

Tags: opera, javascript, firefox

В основном тестирую скрипты на Opera (в данный момент версия 26, тот же движок, что и  в Chrome).
Но стоило попробовать Firefox, обнаружил 2 вещи: принцип адресации переменных другой (если в Опере эта переменная видимая, то в Firefox нашлись такие, которые либо инициализируются с опозданием, либо вообще не объявляются) и неистово ест оперативную память, чего не наблюдается даже в Chrome.
Также наблюдаются ошибки в логах webgl, которые не обнаруживаются в Опере.

Firefox 34.0.5
Windows 8.1 x64

Comment: И в чем вопрос? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Эмм.. из контекста было трудно понять, что вопрос будет вида "Почему такое наблюдается в Firefox?"

Comment: По моей ссылке написано, в частности, "Будьте точны: Если вы зададите нечеткий вопрос, то можете получить такой же нечеткий ответ." В вашем случае нечеткий ответ очевиден: либо есть ошибка  у вас в коде, либо в Firefox, либо ошибки нет, но есть разные технологические решения принятые в движке Opera по сравнению с движком Firefox. Чтобы получить более полезный ответ, задайте более конкретный вопрос.

Comment: @Nickolay, текст по ссылке появился значительно позже, чем задан вопрос.

Comment: @Ni55aN, вопрос еще имеет актуальность?

Comment: @Nofate, да, имеет